# How to compute 99% coverage in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics, percentile

I have a matrix in MATLAB and I need to find the 99% value for each column. In other words, the value such that 99% of the population has a larger value than it. Is there a function in MATLAB for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use QUANTILE function.

```
Y = quantile(X,P);
```

where X is a matrix and P is scalar or vector of probabilities. For example, if P=0.01, the Y will be vector of values for each columns, so that 99% of column values are larger.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution is to use the function [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html) as [yuk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384977/finding-99-coverage-in-matlab/2385024#2385024).

```
Y = quantile(X,0.01);
```

However, you will need the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/) to use the function [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html). A solution that is not dependent on toolboxes can be found by noting that [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html) calls the function [PRCTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/prctile.html), which itself calls the built-in function [INTERP1Q](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1q.html) to do the primary computation. For the general case of a 2-D matrix that contains no [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) values you can compute the quantiles of each column using the following code:

```
P = 0.01;       %# Your probability
S = sort(X);    %# Sort the columns of your data X
N = size(X,1);  %# The number of rows of X
Y = interp1q([0 (0.5:(N-0.5))./N 1]',S([1 1:N N],:),P);  %'# Get the quantiles
```

This should give you the same results as calling [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html), without needing any toolboxes.

Comment: Would you please explain the meaning of 1% probability here? I am trying to implement your script to find the interquantile range for a vector but have not managed yet after hours. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the Statistics Toolbox, there is always

```
y=sort(x);
y(floor(length(y)*0.99))
```

or

```
y(floor(length(y)*0.01))
```

depending on what you meant.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't generally give the same results as QUANTILE.

Comment: @gnovice: oh yes, QUANTILE interpolates and is generally more precise. Good job mimicking it in your answer :-)