# How to find p-values of emperical distribution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding 99% coverage in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384977/finding-99-coverage-in-matlab)

How can I compute P10, P50 and P90 given an emperical distribution?

Where, P90 means that 90% of the estimates (or outcomes) are expected to be bigger than this estimate. P50 means that 50% of the estimates (or outcomes) are expected to be bigger than this estimate.

Comment: @Jonas: I tried `quantile` function in the other question you referred to, however its different from my question. Here P10, P50, P90 represents the 10%, 50% and 90% certainty, respectively, of a value occurring from the values in my empirical distribution. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrocarbon_exploration#Definition_of_oil_reserves

Comment: How is it different? Isn't it as simple as replacing 99 with 10, 50 and 90 as the case may be?

Comment: @yoda: Basically if I have 100 values in my distribution, then `quantile` gives 90 values for 90, 50 values with 50 and 10 values with 10. Whereas in fact there should be just one value for 90, 50 or 10.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html) first. Calling the function as `quantile(x,p)` where `0≤p≤1` will give you a single number that is the quantile. Calling it as `quantile(x,N)` where `N` is an integer will return something else (look in the docs). As an example, try `x=rand(1000,1);quantile(x,0.01)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the statistics toolbox, prctile does the trick. If your data is X, then prctile(X,[10,50,90]) will return the 10th, 50th and 90th percentile.

If not, just sort the data and take the percentiles using indexing. If X has a small number of entries, be careful with interpolating.

Comment: also, quantile(x,[.1,.5,.9]) will return the same values